# Estimating rank and nullity of the composition of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T\colon U\to V$, $R\colon V\to W$ be linear maps between finite dimensional spaces $U$, $V$, $W$, and let dim$(V)=n$. Prove that

1. $\dim\, \ker(RT)\le \dim\, \ker(R)+\dim\, \ker(T)$,
2. $\operatorname{rk}(R)+\operatorname{rk}(T)-n\le \operatorname{rk}(RT)$

Ok so I'm almost certain I'll have to use the fact that $\dim V=\dim\, \ker(R)+ \operatorname{rk}(R)$, but past that I'm a bit stumped, although I'm having trouble understanding what $RT$ is.  Is $RT\colon W\to U$?  I can't see past this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $RT:U \to W$ is a composition of $R$ and $T$.  You perform the maps from the right hand map to the left.  But who is $rk$?

Comment: @PaulSundheim this is one of many notations for rank of a matrix.

Comment: ahhhhh its done like that, thanks.  And yep rk is the rank

Comment: (2) follows from (1) by using the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for the first part: Note that $\ker(RT)$ is a subspace of $U$. Let $T'$ be the restriction of $T$ to $\ker(RT)$. So, we have a map

$$T':\ker(RT) \to V,\text{ }T'(u)=T(u)$$

Clearly, $T'$ is again linear and therefore, we can apply the rank theorem:

$$\dim \ker(RT)=\dim \ker(T')+ \text{rk}(T')\tag{$1$}$$

Now, it is easy to check that $\text{im}(T') \subseteq \ker(R)$ (where $\text{im}(T')$ denotes the image of $T'$). Therefore,

$$\text{rk}(T') \leq \dim \ker(R)\tag{2}$$

Moreover, it is easy to check that $\ker(T')\subseteq \ker(T)$ and therefore,

$$\dim \ker(T') \leq \dim \ker(T)\tag{3}$$

The desired result follows from $(1)$,$(2)$ and $(3)$.

You can solve the second part of the problem with a similar consideration, but here you have to work with the restriction of $R$ to the image of $T$ which is given by

$$R':\text{im}(T)\to W,\text{ }R'(v)=R(v)$$